# Loop through two columns and place in order by date

Tags: php

I have a table with team names and away and home dates, i am trying to display the fixtures by date but not sure whats the best method for this.

```
|Team Name| homedate | awaydate |
|team A   |2017-03-27|2017-04-27|
|team b   |2017-01-27|2017-05-27|
|team c   |2017-06-27|2017-02-27|
```

the output i am looking for is this

```
Home - 2017-01-27 - team b 
Away - 2017-02-27 - team c 
Home - 2017-03-27 - team A 
Away - 2017-04-27 - team A 

ect
```

is this possible and can you link to some references for me.
many kind thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP sorting by date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175837/php-sorting-by-date)

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname"); 
$sql = 'select * from testing';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $key1 = strtotime($row['homedate']).'_Home';
    $key2 = strtotime($row['awaydate']).'_Away';
    $arr[$key1] = $row;
    $arr[$key2] = $row;
}
// now sort the array by keys
 ksort($arr);

 foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
     $str = explode('_', $key);         
     echo $str[1] == 'Home' ? 'Home - '.$val['team_name'].' - '.$val['homedate'].'<br />' : 'Away - '.$val['team_name'].' - '.$val['awaydate'].'<br />';
 }
```